# Local Version of Bernstein Von-Mises Theorem?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, references, central-limit-theorem

The Bernstein-Von Mises theorem says that, under reasonable conditions, the posterior distribution $p(\theta | x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ converges weakly to the normal distribution after suitable rescaling.

I would like to know: under stronger assumptions, does the suitably-rescaled density of the posterior converge pointwise to density of the normal distribution, at least over some compact set? Note that nothing along these lines is implied by the convergence of distributions, since you can have weak convergence of distributions even if you don't have pointwise convergence of densities at any point.

For the usual central limit theorem (or other limit theorems in probability), this sort of result is sometimes known as a local limit theorem, and  Theorem 1 of https://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/BernoulliTrials/LocalLimitTheorem/locallimittheorem.pdf gives a good example of the type of result I'm looking for (though I would prefer one over a continuous space).

So, what I'm really asking is: is there a local Bernstein-Von Mises theorem? If so, can somebody provide a reference?

Comment: Welcome to cross-validated and thanks for the interesting question!